# Rails association caching issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

I have the following model/association setup:

```
class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :assigned_users, class_name: 'User'

  def auto_assign_team_member(project)
    team = project.teams(true).order('last_assigned_contact_at ASC').first
    if team && (user = team.user)
      self.assigned_users << user
      team.update_attribute(:last_assigned_contact_at, Time.now)
    end
  end
end

class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :project
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :teams
  has_many :projects, through: :teams
  has_and_belongs_to_many :assigned_contacts, class_name: 'Contact'
end

class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :teams
  has_many :users, through: :teams
end
```

I also have a collection of `Contact` instances which I traverse and execute the `auto_assign_team_member` method. My issue is that the `team` lvar returns the same team for *almost* every execution. I have two records in the `teams` table and my intention is to distribute team members evenly into the `Contact#assigned_users` association.

In console, it works:

```
project.teams(true).order('last_assigned_contact_at ASC').first #=> Team(user_id: 1)
project.teams(true).order('last_assigned_contact_at ASC').first.update_attribute(:last_assigned_contact_at, Time.now)
project.teams(true).order('last_assigned_contact_at ASC').first #=> Team(user_id: 2)
```

Any idea where I'm going wrong here?

**EDIT** If anyone is interested I have created a tiny application to reproduce this https://github.com/injekt/teamr

You can simple run `rake db:seed` to run the test data, the output should be evenly distributed over each User, rather than displaying the same user each time.

**EDIT** As it turns out, doing `update_attribute(:last_assigned_contact_at, 'now()')` instead works fine. So maybe Rails is doing something funky under the hood? I realize this needs high precision but I would think rails could handle that

Comment: I should also note that I am using `postgresql` which has millisecond precision when using a `timestamp` type

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the issue is Rails rounding off usec from any Time object, probably because only PostgreSQL actually supports that kind of precision with they "timestamp without time zone" data type.

Timestamp attributes are treated differently from other attributes, with this module defining a custom setter for them: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3-2-stable/activerecord/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/time_zone_conversion.rb

Time objects get rounded before comparing and assigning the value https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3-2-stable/activerecord/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/time_zone_conversion.rb#L46

The weird issue is that for built in Rails timestamp columns, the precision is there.
This is because the built in timestamps bypass the custom setters by calling `write_attribute(:column, value)`, which just flat out inserts the whole time value, along with any usec.

So the fix there is to do this instead of the `team.update_attribute` call

```
team.send(:write_attribute, :last_assigned_contact_at, Time.current)
team.save
```

This effectively bypasses the whole custom setter logic and handles the value just like it handles the built in timestamp updates.

Comment: it seems this didn't actually work. I know we discussed it on the IRC channel afterwards but I couldn't figure out what it could be. I'm opening the question again, thanks for your input and time.